# How to read file in J2ME using getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, java-me, filepath

My J2ME program structure is like as follow.

File Read

```
   -src
   -res   
   -test
      -abc.txt
   -java libraries
```

Here abc.txt is in test folder

Now I am reading file as follow:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test/abc.txt");
```

after executing above statement, it will raise exception.

Now please help me out. How to read file and which path I have to give in getResourceAsStrream?

Comment: Are you running a *.jar file? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You missed `res` in your file path. Use like this,

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/test/abc.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put "abc.txt" in the res folder and then access it as

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc.txt");
```

After doing this you should clear your project and refresh it...then run it works..